# Stop asynchronous UITableViewCell image loading when cell is not visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, lazy-loading

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ application with latest SDK.

This is the code I use to load images asynchronously for `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ((groups != nil) && (groups.count > 0))
    {
        GroupCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[GroupCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        // Configure the cell...
        Group* group = [groups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.GroupNameLabel.text = group.Name;
        // TODO: Poner el estado.
        if (group.Photo)
            cell.GroupImageView.image = group.Photo;
        else
        {
            // download the photo asynchronously
            NSString *urlString =
                [NSString stringWithFormat:kGetGroupImageURL, [group.GroupId intValue]];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

            [ImageTool downloadImageWithURL:url completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
                if (succeeded)
                {
                    // change the image in the cell
                    cell.GroupImageView.image = image;

                    // cache the image for use later (when scrolling up)
                    group.Photo = image;
                }
            }];
        }

        return cell;
    }
    else
        return nil;
}
```

And the loader:

```
#import "ImageTool.h"

@implementation ImageTool

+ (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
             completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image))completionBlock
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if ( !error )
                               {
                                   UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                   completionBlock(YES,image);
                               } else{
                                   completionBlock(NO,nil);
                               }
                           }];
}
```

But it seems it's not going to work because I don't handle if the cell for which I'm loading the image it is still visible.

**How can I handle if the cell is still visible?**

I have found this [article](http://blog.oleganza.com/post/207635553/the-efficient-way-to-load-and-render-images-in-the), but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: BTW, unrelated to your question, but I assume you have a `didReceiveMemoryWarning` that purges the images from `groups`? If you used a `NSCache`, this would handle memory pressure automatically, but if you're going to manually keep track of this, just make sure you respond to memory pressure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally handle this by checking to see if the cell is still visible using the `UITableView` method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which returns `nil` if the cell for that index path is no longer visible. Note, this method is not to be confused with the similarly named `UITableViewDataSource` method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
if (group.Photo)
    cell.GroupImageView.image = group.Photo;
else
{
    // don't forget to `nil` or use placeholder for `GroupImageView` because if
    // the cell is reused, you might see the old image for the other row momentarily
    // while the new image is being retrieved

    cell.GroupImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];

    // download the photo asynchronously
    NSString *urlString =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:kGetGroupImageURL, [group.GroupId intValue]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    [ImageTool downloadImageWithURL:url completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
        if (succeeded)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                GroupCell *updateCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                if (updateCell) 
                {
                    // change the image in the cell
                    updateCell.GroupImageView.image = image;
                }

                // cache the image for use later (when scrolling up)
                group.Photo = image;
            });
        }
    }];
}
```

Note, if the completion block of `sendAsynchronousRequest` is not submitted to the main queue (e.g. you may do something computationally expensive that you don't want to tie up the main queue with), you might further dispatch the UI update to the main queue as shown above. You can do it either here, like shown above, or in the `downloadImageWithURL`. But make sure to update the UI on the main queue (and to avoid synchronization issues, update `group`, there, too). Since you've specified the main queue for your operation queue, though, this is not a critical issue.

And as I point out in my code comments, if you're retrieving an image for a cell that has been reused, don't forget to reset the `GroupImageView.image` property to `nil`, too. If you don't, you may see the previous image for the reused cell show up momentarily while the request for the new row is in progress.

---

Alternatively, you should use a `UIImageView` category, such as provided by [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which takes care of all of this for you (including cache management).

As an aside, it also handles a subtle issue, which your code doesn't, namely where you scroll really quickly through a long tableview on a slow internet connection. You implementation wouldn't load the images for the currently visible cells until all of the other cells' images have loaded (since there can be only five concurrent `NSURLConnection` objects at a time). These `UIImageView` categories generally cancel the old requests for cells that have been reused, which ensures that the UI is presenting the images that the user is actually looking at more quickly.

Comment: Just a note: the completion handler actually *will* execute on the main thread: in `downloadImageWithURL:completionBlock:`,  `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` specifies the "Main Queue" where the handler block will be eventually dispatched. Nonetheless, for better robustness, I would prefer to use Rob's code verbatim anyway   ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Quite right. I didn't notice that they were using the main queue for the `NSURLConnection`.